How to achieve outlet in next js using app router
I have a simple next app with the following structure
app(dir)
page.js
layout.js
student(dir)
--page.js

In this consider layout.js contains
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}

and app page.js contains
export default function Page() {
  return <h1>Hello, from app page</h1>;
}

`
and student page.js contains
export default function Page() {
  return <h1>Hello, Student</h1>;
}

Now in this
->when I navigate to localhost:3000 it shows
Hello, from app page
->>when I navigate to localhost:3000/student it shows
Hello, Student
In this I need to show app directory page.js content in locahost:3000/student
Like this:
  Hello, from app page
     Hello, student 

I can define this in layout.js in the app directory and achieve this but when i'm in localhost:3000 it shows the
Hello, from app page
Hello, from app page

two times
Do I need to check
I know I'm missing something but i'm not able to figure it out
or do i need to check when the user is in localhost:3000 and put a if condition to make that possible

So basically for ex. you are trying to load Student navbar on student page & home navbar when outside of student page ?

Problem :

How to change layout (navbar) when in student page

Cause :
Root layout nests all other layouts (which is right, & expected behavior).
Possible Solution :

Instead of adding content(navbar) in root layout, create individual layout file for student.
in your root layout file don't place anything, as root layout wraps everything. Hence create individual layout file for student inside that place the student content (ex. student's navbar) now this will be visible only on students page.

Here is a small code I made in which, when user on home page sees homepage navbar, & when on students page sees student navbar.
Folder Structure :
src
└── app
    ├── (home)            // route group - to keep home related pages together
    │   ├── about
    │   │   └── page.js      // just for example
    │   ├── layout.js        // home layout
    │   └── page.js          // home page
    ├── layout.js            // root layout (required)
    └── student
        ├── layout.js        // student layout
        └── page.js          // student page

layout.js at src\app\layout.js :
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <div>
          Root Navbar
        </div>
        <main>{children}</main>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

layout.js at src\app\(home)\layout.js :
import Link from 'next/link'

export default function HomeLayout({
    children,
}) {
    return (
        <section>

            <div>
                Homepage Navbar

                <Link href={'/about'}>
                    About
                </Link>
            </div>

            {children}
        </section>
    )
}

page.js (Homepage) at src\app\(home)\page.js :
import Link from 'next/link'

export default async function Home() {

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Home Page</h3>
      <Link href={'/student'}>
        Go to students page
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}

Student :
layout.js at src\app\student\layout.js :
export default function StudentLayout({
    children,
}) {
    return (
        <section>

            <div>
                Student Navbar
            </div>

            {children}
        </section>
    )
}

page.js (Students Page) at src\app\(home)\page.js :
import Link from 'next/link'

export default async function StudentPage() {

return (
    <div>
      <h3>Hello, from  Student Page</h3>
      <Link href={'/'}>
        Go to Home page
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}

Explaination :
Root Navbar will be visible in all pages (students pages & home group pages ), Homepage Navbar in home group pages (means also in about page) & Students navbar in student page.

When you now open http://localhost:3000/ (you dont need to pass route group name in url nextjs ignores it) you will see page containing this :
Root Navbar - this from layout.js at src\app\layout.js
Homepage Navbar About - this from layout.js at src\app(home)\layout.js
Home Page - src\app(home)\page.js
Go to students page - src\app(home)\page.js


Rough Diagram :
When you goto http://localhost:3000 :
<RootLayout>
    RootNavbar
    <HomeLayout>
        HomeNavbar
        {
            Pages on route / are loaded in here 
        }
    </HomeLayout>
</RootLayout>


Now when you goto http://localhost:3000/student :
Root Navbar - this from layout.js at src\app\layout.js
Student Navbar - this from layout.js at src\app\student\layout.js
Hello, from Student Page - src\app\student\page.js
Go to Home page - src\app\student\page.js
enter code here


Rough Diagram :
When you goto http://localhost:3000/student :
<RootLayout>
    RootNavbar
    <StudentLayout>
        HomeNavbar
        {
            Pages on /student are loaded in here ,
        }
    </StudentLayout>
</RootLayout>

As per your use case, you may remove Root Navbar.
Please Read :

Layouts : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts
Route Groups : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups
Opting specific segments into a layout : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups#opting-specific-segments-into-a-layout


If you have any doubts, then please leave a comment (I will update answer if necessary)

